# Undirected graph contains a cycle

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

How do I prove that the connected undirected graph having 10 nodes and 10 edges
contains a cycle.

Comment: What do you mean by "the" connected undirected graph having $10$ vertices and $10$ edges? Do you have a specific graph in mind, or are you asking how to prove this for any connected undirected graph having $10$ vertices and $10$ edges?

Comment: for any undirected graph

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**: Any tree with $n$ vertices can have atmost $n-1$ edges.

Comment: you mean to say $n-1$ edges

Comment: @TechJ yes I hope you got it

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have framed the answer using hint provided by you.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that it is not cyclic, so then it means it is a tree.

But for tree we have number of edges 1 less than number of vertices i.e. $n=n-1$

$n=10-1=9$ which contradicts the given statement.

Hence our assumption is wrong, so there exists a cycle.